# For homeomorphism $f:X\to Y$, show that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y})=\mathcal{B}_{X}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> My question is that if a function $f: X\to Y$ is homeomorphism, show that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y})=\mathcal{B}_{X}$.
>   where $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y}):=\{f^{-1}(A): A\in \mathcal{B}_{Y}\}$.

I try to use the continuity of $f$ but I am stuck get the relation between $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y})\subset \mathcal{B}_{X}$ or $ \mathcal{B}_{X}\subset f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y})$. Actually, I konw that $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y})\neq \mathcal{B}_{X}.$

Comment: This is very similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3354335/700480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that $\{f^{-1}(B): B \in \mathcal{B}_Y\}$ is a sigma algebra on $X$ and contains the open sets.

Every open set $A$ in $X$  has the form $A=f^{-1}(B)$ where $B$ an open subest of $Y$  since $f$ is a homeomorphism, so we have $\mathcal{B}_X \subset f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y)$ because $\mathcal{B}_X$ is the smallest sigma algebra that contains the open subsets of $X$

Comment: Do you mean that every open set $O \subset \mathcal{B}_{Y}$, we have $f^{-1}(O)\in \mathcal{B}_{Y} $ because $f$ is continuous. So $f^{-1}( \mathcal{B}_{Y})\subset \mathcal{B}_{X}$. Due to $f^{-1}$ is continuous, we have $f(T)\in \mathcal{B}_{Y}$, $\forall T \subset X $ wich is open set. Thus, $\mathcal{B}_{X}\subset f^{-1}( \mathcal{B}_{Y}) $

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui I edited my answer

Comment: I am a little confused about the $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y)\subset \mathcal{B}_X$. Can I prove this by $\forall O\in  \mathcal{B}_Y$, $f^{-1}(O)\in \mathcal{B}_X$? The logic is a little confusing because $f^{-1}(O)\in f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y) $ also.

Comment: In your post you mentioned that they are not equal ans indeed only the set inequality in my answer holds.

Comment: So how to prove the $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_Y)\subset \mathcal{B}_X$?

Comment: This is not true in general

Comment: you mean $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}_{Y})=\mathcal{B}_{X}$ is not true?

Comment: I believe yes...you have mentioned this already in your post also

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more? So how to prove that ?